# Kattis Challenge: Phone List, 4-Second Time Limit Exceeded, C#

Tags: c#, performance, time

Using the online automated testing system Kattis, I'm challenged (in C#) with the task of creating a list of phone numbers then finding out if any of them is a prefix or another.

(see: https://ncpc.idi.ntnu.no/ncpc2007/ncpc2007problems.pdf, task A)

Providing the answer was relatively easy, but no matter how I try I cannot escape getting the Result: Time Limit Exceeded, with some further information saying it took over 4 seconds to run the program (by an automated program).

I have tried rewriting it from scratch several times, and I've tried every existing suggestion I could find available on the internet. I find myself at a total loss at what to do, mostly because in the end I cannot be sure what is actually wrong.

[This code](http://pastebin.com/9AiYtg0S) was suggested on a similar (but unresolved) [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31361512/kattis-issue-phone-list-c-sharp), and did not do the magic - yet it's the finest I've seen thus far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace PhoneList
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Save number of test cases.
        var numTestCases = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        // Do this for each test case.
        for (int i = 0; i < numTestCases; i++)
        {
            // Save number of phone numbers.
            var numPhoneNumbers = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            // Save all phonenumbers in the list.
            var phoneNumbersList = new List<string>();
            for (int j = 0; j < numPhoneNumbers; j++)
            {
                string number = Console.ReadLine().Trim();

                // Add to list.
                phoneNumbersList.Add(number);
            }

            // Write output.
            if (phoneNumbersList.All(n => !phoneNumbersList.Except(new[] { n }).Any(o => o.StartsWith(n))))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("YES");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("NO");
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: If this code is functional, this probably belongs on [codereview.se]

Comment: Sort your list of phone numbers. Then you only need to compare the `n` item to the `n-1` entry until you find one that breaks the rule or reach the end of the list.

Comment: Ya, that got me passed the second test! But Time Limit Exceeded still triggered on the third test... 

I replaced the LINQ-query with * Check update in OP *

Comment: In your `if` statement, use a `break` to break out of the loop. Once you've found a single bad number, there is no need to waste time checking the rest.

Comment: Woops, forgetting the break was stupid. Didn't make any difference though... Still got stuck on the third test case with the program timing out... 

Ya, I found two threads about the exactly same problem, but without solution. But they were pretty old though.

Comment: It may not be good enough to read all the items and then sort. What you might have to do is sort them *as you read them*. You could use the `SortedList` (or `SortedDictionary`) class or implement your own binary sort tree (not hard to do). Then as you go to insert a new item you will check the items around it to see if they break the rule. That way you can quit early and not even read the rest of the data if you know the set is not consistent

Comment: I tried using a SortedSet and setting n-1 as a temp variable to compare n with and break if match. Still stopped at the third test, but I will try your other solutions :)

Comment: See also [Kattis Phone List c#, Time Limit Exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37193101/kattis-phone-list-c-time-limit-exceeded/69575128#69575128)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried sorting the phone numbers list (alphabetically) once all the numbers are added, and then checking if item n+1 starts with item n?

```
phoneNumbersList.Sort((x,y) => string.Compare(x, y));

var consistent = true;
for (var j = 0; j < phoneNumbersList.Count - 1; ++j)
{
   if (phoneNumbersList[j + 1].StartsWith(phoneNumbersList[j]))
   {
        consistent = false;
        break;
   }
}

Console.WriteLine(consistent ? "YES" : "NO");
```

Comment: I had attempted to use sorting before to no avail, but applying your suggestion did manage to solve the Time Limit Exceeded issue. However instead of it I was greeted with a Wrong Answer-response, suggesting that the code does not actually do what's intended..

Comment: Edit: Tweaking the code a bit fixed the Wrong Answer-response, and got me one step further in the Kattis testing process (step 3/5 as opposed to 2/5) before going back to giving me the same Time Limit Exceeded-response.

Comment: Their testing data is secret, so I really wouldn't know. All I have to go on is some sample data, which I pass with flying colors on my end, but the sample data is just about only the first check they do.

Answer (score 0):

Not always the shortest and finest is the best :-) Try the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Samples
{
    class PhoneListProcessor
    {
        const int MaxCount = 10000;
        const int MaxDigits = 10;
        Dictionary<int, bool> phoneNumberInfo = new Dictionary<int, bool>(MaxCount * MaxDigits);
        public bool Process(IEnumerable<string> phoneNumbers, bool readToEnd)
        {
            phoneNumberInfo.Clear();
            using (var e = phoneNumbers.GetEnumerator())
            {
                while (e.MoveNext())
                {
                    if (Process(e.Current)) continue;
                    if (readToEnd)
                    {
                        while (e.MoveNext()) { }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        bool Process(string phoneNumber)
        {
            var phoneNumberInfo = this.phoneNumberInfo;
            int phoneCode = 0;
            int digitPos = 0;
            bool hasSuffix = true;
            while (true)
            {
                phoneCode = 11 * phoneCode + (phoneNumber[digitPos] - '0' + 1);
                bool isLastDigit = ++digitPos >= phoneNumber.Length;
                bool isPhoneNumber;
                if (hasSuffix && phoneNumberInfo.TryGetValue(phoneCode, out isPhoneNumber))
                {
                    if (isPhoneNumber || isLastDigit) return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    phoneNumberInfo.Add(phoneCode, isLastDigit);
                    if (isLastDigit) return true;
                    hasSuffix = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var processor = new PhoneListProcessor();
            int testCount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            for (int testIndex = 0; testIndex < testCount; testIndex++)
            {
                int count = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                var numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, count).Select(_ => Console.ReadLine());
                bool readToEnd = testIndex + 1 < testCount;
                bool valid = processor.Process(numbers, readToEnd);
                Console.WriteLine(valid ? "YES" : "NO");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Basically what is does is building on the fly and using a variant of a [dictionary prefix trie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) under the task constraints and specifics. Each phone number or prefix is encoded as integer number of base 11 with no zeroes (each digit is incremented, so instead of 0-9 we have 1-10) in order to distinguish numbers with leading zeroes from the same numbers without leading zeroes as requested.

Comment: It passed the 2 first checks, but failed on the 3rd (out of 5) because of giving a wrong answer. I do not know what, or how, they test passed the 1st check.

Comment: @JuliusMikkelä Ok, try the updated code, hopefully it should pass now.

Comment: @JuliusMikkelä Please don't understand me wrong, I don't care for earning reputation points, this puzzle is really interesting me from the performance perspective (general and compared to C/C++ solutions). Have you tried my latest code (the initial had a boring bug)? Did it pass? Resulting time?

Answer (score 0):

I have two suggestions:

1. Instead of sorting alphabetically with `phoneNumbers.Sort();`, try sorting by length: `numbers.Sort((a, b) => a.Length - b.Length);`. The intuition is that since it's not possible for a string with a longer length to be a prefix of a shorter string, we can skip checking those and save some work (early bailout as soon as we find an inconsistency is important).
2. Since the phone lengths are only 10 digits long, it's feasible to iterate over it and store every prefix in a HashSet. The HashSet gives us O(1) lookup time on all previously-computed prefixes, so the time complexity per test case is O(n) for the checks and O(n log(n)) for the up-front sort cost.

Here's the code:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace PhoneList
{
    class Program
    {
        static bool IsConsistent(List<string> numbers)
        {
            numbers.Sort((a, b) => a.Length - b.Length);
            var prefixes = new HashSet<string>();

            foreach (var n in numbers)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i < n.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (prefixes.Contains(n.Substring(0, i)))
                    {
                        return false;
                    }
                }

                prefixes.Add(n);
            }

            return true;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int testCases = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = 0; i < testCases; i++)
            {
                int phoneNumbersCount = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                var numbers = new List<string>();

                for (int j = 0; j < phoneNumbersCount; j++)
                {
                    numbers.Add(Console.ReadLine());
                }

                Console.WriteLine(IsConsistent(numbers) ? "YES" : "NO");
            }
        }
    }
}
```